# GCC Makefile Define

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have some C code that I want to do some tests on. It uses malloc, calloc, and free through out the code. I want to change those functions to a custom function that internally calls the original function. For example:

```
emxArray->size = (int *)malloc((unsigned int)(sizeof(int) * numDimensions));
```

would become:

```
emxArray->size = (int *)myMalloc((unsigned int)(sizeof(int) * numDimensions));
```

where myMalloc is:

```
void* myMalloc(unsigned size)
{
    if (size < 8)
    {
        //printf("*** Bumped from %d....\n", size);
        size = 8;
    }
    allocated += size;
    return malloc(size);
}
```

As you can see, myMalloc internally calls malloc. It just does some extra stuff. I wanted to replace the usage of malloc through out the code with myMalloc. I have done this successfully by going through all the code and replacing malloc with myMalloc manually, but this is far from ideal. I will be replacing this code on a test only basis, thus the production code should contain only malloc calls. I realize I could also do this with a script, but wanted to just use a define statement in the Makefile:

```
-Dmalloc=myMalloc
```

But that also replaces malloc in the myMalloc function, which causes an infinite recursive situation. I tried changing the malloc call in the myMalloc function to malloc_d, and added a second define to the Makefile.

```
-Dmalloc=myMalloc -Dmalloc_d=malloc
```

I was thinking that the first define would not replace the malloc_d (which it didn't) and that the second define would only change the malloc_d (which it didn't). I got the same recursive situation. Is there anyway to do this with Makefile defines? Or are multipass pre-compile situations going to always mess this up?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so I have started looking at the LD_PRELOAD option that has been pointed out. I thought I had a workable solution, however, I am still having trouble! Here is what I did...

1. I moved myMalloc() and myFree() out of the main file and into its own file. I then compiled it into a shared library using:
   gcc -shared -o libMyMalloc.so -fPIC myMalloc.c
2. I then added the following 'dummy functions' to the main file:

   void* myMalloc(unsigned size)
   {
     void* ptr;
     return ptr;
   }

   void myFree(void* ptr)
   {
   }

As you can see, they do nothing.

3. I added the following defines to the make file:
   -Dmalloc=myMalloc \
   -Dfree=myFree
4. I compiled the code and ran it against the libMyMalloc.so library I created:

   LD_PRELOAD=/home/rad/Desktop/myMalloc/libMyMalloc.so ./testRegress

However, I am still not getting it to run with the myMalloc functions that are defined in the libMyMalloc.so file.

Comment: Take a look at [liballoc](https://github.com/blanham/liballoc). It shows an example of how you can achieve this.

Comment: More specifically, [What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick/426260#426260)

Comment: I started to try this, but found myself in the same situation. While I can make a new malloc library that contains my malloc wrapper (called malloc), create a sharable library (.so) and run with it, I still have the problem with recursion if my malloc function is called 'malloc' and needs to call the std malloc. That's why I wanted a new function called myMalloc.

Comment: I'm not sure you are right in redefining `malloc` like you do. Do you know [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), it could help you to find `malloc` related bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution and wanted to share. Thank you to everyone that contributed and pointed me in the right direction.

I ended up creating my custom library code and compiling it into a shared library:

```
gcc -shared -o libtmalloc.so -fPIC tmalloc.c
```

I then modified the makefile to use the shared library and globally define 'malloc' to my custom function name (which internally calls malloc()) to malloc_t, as well as calloc() and free():

```
gcc -L/home/path/to/mallocTrace -Wall -o test test.c lib/coder/*.c -lm -ltmalloc \
-Dmalloc=malloc_t \
-Dcalloc=calloc_t \
-Dfree=free_t
```

The defines changed all the function calls for me which were linked to the implementation in the shared library. Because I am using a shared library (which is already compiled), I didn't have to worry about my makefile defines causing a recursive call situation in my custom functions. With this usage, I can take any pre-generated C code from my other tools and observe the memory usage with these simple makefile changes and using my custom malloc trace library.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to not call `malloc` directly in your code: If you choose a different name (say `MALLOC`), it's trivial to switch to a custom allocator.

Example code:

```
#ifndef MALLOC
#define MALLOC malloc
#endif
```

For test builds, you'd do `-DMALLOC=myMalloc`.

It gets more complicated if for some reason you want keep the calls to `malloc`. Then you'd have to add something like the following **after all standard library headers have been included**:

```
#ifdef USE_MY_MALLOC
#undef malloc
#define malloc(SIZE) myMalloc(SIZE)
#endif
```

You can call the standard library function by using parens, ie

```
void* myMalloc(unsigned size)
{
    ...
    return (malloc)(size);
}
```

and enable it via `-DUSE_MY_MALLOC`.

---

Considering the additional requirements given in the comments, two approaches come to mind:

- pre-process the generated source, textually replacing calls to `malloc`
- intercept inclusion of `stdlib.h` (assuming that's where MATLAB gets its `malloc` declaration from)

Your own version of `stdlib.h` would look something like this:

```
#ifndef MY_STDLIB_H_
#define MY_STDLIB_H_

#include "/usr/include/stdlib.h"

#undef malloc
#define malloc(SIZE) myMalloc(SIZE)

#endif
```

Then, you can conditionally add the directory where you've placed that file to the include path. Also note that this is not a particularly robust solution, but it might work for you anyway.

Comment: Wont this just take effect in one file? I have several files that have malloc. The problem is that this is C code that is generated from another tool (Matlab), so I have no control over how it is generated and cannot use another name like MALLOC.

Comment: Technically, this answer is very good. However, I would strongly advise against redefining standard names by the means of preprocessor macros. Just imagine what would happen if another programmer also had the brilliant idea to replace `malloc()` by placing a `#define` in a header. You'd get into a situation where some source files would use `myMalloc()` and some others would use his implementation without a compiler error. Madness ensues... I think I remember the SDL for Mac pulling off a similar trick with `main()`... madness ensued.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer to a function. In the normal case, make it point to malloc. In debugging mode, let it point to you function.

In some h file:

```
extern void *(*myMalloc)(size_t size);
```

In one of you c files:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
void *(*myMalloc)(size_t size) = dMalloc;
#else
void *(*myMalloc)(size_t size) = malloc; // derived from libc
#endif
```